# MySQL - How to get the rowid of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a service that queries records from a mysql table and then pushes that to another database. This push happens periodically. My problem is I need to identify what was the last record sent to the new database, so when my service is called again I can send the remaining records.

If the table has a timestamp column then this would be easy, but it does not and I do not have access to change the original table. So is there a way to identify a row by an ID given by MySQL it self, so that I can send the rest of the rows after that row location. If I can identify the last row sent, I can store that in a table and then query from that point onward.

```
CREATE TABLE alarm_ctxs 
(   id_alarm binary(16) NOT NULL, 
    id_ctx binary(16) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_alarm,id_ctx) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Generally and generically no. Show us a schema of it by publishing the output of `show create table thatTableName`

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets. There is no 'onward'

Comment: The table needs an `auto_increment` column.  That is the canonical approach.

Comment: @Drew , The main issue is I do not have access to change the existing table structure so I have to work with the existing structure. Following is what I get when I do a "show create table" 
'CREATE TABLE `alarm_ctxs` (
  `id_alarm` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `id_ctx` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alarm`,`id_ctx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: well you could do something like a `NOT IN (...)` or a `LEFT JOIN` looking at `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP, you can use mysql_insert_id() to retrieve the ID of the last insert, you need to create in this table a primary key auto increment too. Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`......);
$the_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

MySql has something like that too, take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: First inquire as to the table structure. It does not appear that he is inserting into a table that has an `auto_increment`, but rather that he wants to know the last info there. So generally these wild guess answers are not too helpful. Please improve that strategy moving forward.

Comment: By the way I just looked at your other answers (cuz I was bored). Welcome to Stackoverflow. You are doing a nice job. Keep up the good work. Not my downvote.

Comment: Thanks first day here answering questions =)